# Datatables table tool design change?

Tags: jquery

I am using datatables table tool plugin for exporting to csv file..the button usually shown on the top of the datatables...but i want to show below the table how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

post your code

you need to edit the "sDom" parameter to position it.

check out this example where it is added to top and bottom http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/multi_instance.html

Comment: "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip' This is to  show table tools export button...which is at the top